# Unmarshalling YAML array of multiple types

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

I'm still somewhat new to Go and could use some help. I have a snippet of YAML I'm tying to unmarshall into something I can work with.

YAML:

```yaml
script:
  - executable: python
  - script.py
```

These are the structs I currently have. I'm able to get `Executable` but I can't the list of arguments.

```golang
type Config struct {
    Script []ScriptConfig `yaml:"script"`
}

type ScriptConfig struct {
    Executable string   `yaml:"executable"`
    Arguments  []string `yaml:",flow"`
}
```

Is anyone able to help me out? How can I get a list of the arguments?

Comment: all continuous rows with `-` are considered array items so script property is an array. The right representation would be `Script []string`. the first item in the array is the executable and remaining are arguments.

Comment: @gp.So I've tried that. That gets the arguments but it doesn't get the executable. I can't figure out how to get both. I can only get one or the other it seems.

Comment: got it. the first item is not a string. using `ScriptConfig interface{}` will allow the decoding however, you will then need to check the type and typecast.

Answer (score 4):

script property is array where first item is a struct and 2nd onwards are string.
option 1: make ScriptConfig interface but after decoding you would need to typecast and further decode the first ScriptConfig entry.

```
type ScriptConfig interface{}

type Config struct {
    Script []ScriptConfig `yaml:"script"`
}
```

option 2: make ScriptConfig another struct with arg and executable both properties and use a custom marshaler. However, you would have one of the properties nil that you would need to care for and it's also not very clean from your entity model.

```
type ScriptConfig struct {
    Executable string `yaml:"executable"`
    Arg string
}

func (s *ScriptConfig) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    var exec struct {
        Executable string `yaml:"executable"`
    }
    if err := unmarshal(&exec); err != nil {
        // will be error for 2nd row onwards
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    var arg string
    if err := unmarshal(&arg); err != nil {
        // will be error for 1st row
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    s.Executable = exec.Executable
    s.Arg = arg
    return nil
}
```

option 3: use `yaml.Node` and temporary structures and do the conversion with custom marshaler to the actual structs that you want. This is slight complex but you get clean entity model.

```
type tmpConfig struct {
    // Script []ScriptConfig `yaml:"script"`
    Script []yaml.Node `yaml:"script"`
}
type tmpExecutable struct {
    Executable string `yaml:"executable"`
}

type ScriptConfig struct {
    Executable string
    Args       []string
}
type Config struct {
    Script ScriptConfig `yaml:"script"`
}

func (c *Config) UnmarshalYAML(v *yaml.Node) error {
    var tmp tmpConfig
    if err := v.Decode(&tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    l := len(tmp.Script)
    if l < 1 {
        return nil
    }

    var tmpexec tmpExecutable
    if err := tmp.Script[0].Decode(&tmpexec); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    //copy the executable property from the decoded temp struct
    c.Script.Executable = tmpexec.Executable

    c.Script.Args = make([]string, l-1)
    //copy the args skipping first one
    for i := 1; i < len(tmp.Script); i++ {
        c.Script.Args[i-1] = tmp.Script[i].Value
    }

    fmt.Println(c)
    return nil
}
```

A general note: check if the yaml itself can be structured with separate executable and args so the yaml also looks more readable. If not then the above options should help.